# What's the port 5433 in postgres

Tags: 22.04, postgresql

The `PostgreSQL` default port is `5432`, but I found two ports in Ubuntu, one is `5432`, the other is `5433`.

```
# ss -nlapt | grep postgres

LISTEN    0      200                127.0.0.1:5432                     0.0.0.0:*     users:(("postgres",pid=1862,fd=6))
LISTEN    0      224                127.0.0.1:5433                     0.0.0.0:*     users:(("postgres",pid=1864,fd=3))
```

I can connect to `5432` by using `pgadmin`. But I can't connect to `5433` with the same user.

I don't know what command can be used to debug this port `5433`.

What's the port `5433` and how to debug this port to check what it is?

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of PostgreSQL installed? If so, one will use the default 5432 and the other would use the next available port, which is generally 5433 